# Magento 2 create new tab and add customer grid collection on product add/edit page in admin

Tags: magento2, collection, grid, tabs

I am using magento 2.3 and i want add custom tab in Product edit page on admin and add grid collection of customer in custom tab. So any one know How i can do that.

Thank you.

Comment: This will help you for adding tab: https://magenticians.com/add-custom-tab-magento-2/

Comment: Thank you @Ravi but i need load customer in product admin edit page on tab.

Comment: @virupatel find any answer?